# Deleting Previous Notifications Android using cancelAll method

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a question regarding the cancelAll() method in the notificationManager class. I have referred to both the api and Google's guide [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageYourNotifications%29). For the method it states that it will remove all notifications previously issued, but does that mean that it will delete notifications pushed by other apps as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean that it will delete notifications pushed by other apps as well??

No, you can cancel only what you have issued. I.e. manage *your* notifications.

That is true for almost everything your app does because you are not supposed to break out of your sandbox.

Comment: That's great to know. One more thing, will it only cancel notifications that have been pushed i.e. in the notification bar or will it delete notifications that are still pending and will be sent at a later time?

Comment: I *think* it should cancel them as well but you should try to see if that's true